# How can I transfer a CSV file from the output of python script into SQL?

Tags: python, sql, database, command-prompt, arcgis

I have a python script that takes data from my ARCGIS Online account and brings down into a CSV into a specified file. The script can be found at the bottom. I then want to take the CSV file and put it into SQL. I want the process to be automated. I run the script in the command prompt (example in the image). Can i modify my python script so it puts the file into SQL? or is there an additional command i need to run in the command prompt? I am very new to SQL and  python.

```
>>> 
... import ago
... import urllib2
... import zipfile
... import json
... 
... 
... # ID of the feature service you want to export
... featureService_ID = "f4a06f02b1dd4b1f8904ed0d4e8713bd"
... # Output format  Shapefile | CSV | File Geodatabase
... output_format = 'Shapefile'
... # Local folder where the data will be downloaded (include slash at the end)
... download_folder = "D:/Temp/"
... # ArcGIS user credentials to authenicate against the portal
... credentials = { 'userName' : 'XXXXX', 'passWord' : 'YYYYYY'}
... # Address of your ArcGIS portal
... portal_url = r"https://www.arcgis.com/"
... 
... download_file = download_folder + 'download.zip'
... 
... 
... def downloadFile(url, filename, token):
...     """
...     Downloads a file from the given URL.
...     :param url: URL from which to download the file
...     :param filename: Name of file to store the download locally. Proper permissions are assumed.
...     :param token: Token for the portal identity
...     :return:
...     """
...     print ("...Downloading")
...     req = urllib2.urlopen(url + "?token=" + token)
...     CHUNK = 16 * 1024
...     with open(filename, 'wb') as fp:
...         while True:
...             chunk = req.read(CHUNK)
...             if not chunk: break
...             fp.write(chunk)
... 
... def extractZIP(filename,folder):
...     """
...     Extracts the contents of the zip file into the specified folder.
...     :param filename: The name of the ZIP archive to unpack. The file is assumed to exist.
...     :param folder: The target folder to hold the content of the ZIP archive. Proper permissions are assumed.
...     :return:
...     """
...     print ("...Extracting")
...     zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(filename)
...     zfile.extractall(folder)
... 
... 
... print ("...Starting")
... # initialize the portal helper class
... # ago.py is part of the 10.3 python install
... agol_helper = ago.AGOLHelper(portal_url)
... print ("...Authenticating against your Portal ")
... # login
... agol_helper.login(credentials['userName'], credentials['passWord'])
... 
... # export url and parameters 
... export_url = "{}/content/users/{}/export".format(agol_helper.secure_url, agol_helper.username)
... 
... export_parameters = {
...     'token': agol_helper.token,
...     'itemId': featureService_ID,
...     'title': "Temp-" + str(int(round(time.time() * 1000))),
...     'exportFormat': output_format,
...     'f' :'json'
... }
... # launching async export request
... export_data = agol_helper.url_request(export_url, export_parameters, request_type="POST")
... 
... if export_data is  None:
...     print "ERROR: Can't find a feature service with id: " + featureService_ID
...     print "TIP:   Navigate to the item details page of your feature service, and get the id from the URL"
... else:
...     print ("...Exporting data")
...     # retrieve the itemId for the export
...     exportItemId = export_data['exportItemId']
...     # retrieve the jobId to watch the export progress
...     jobId = export_data['jobId']
...     status = "processing"
... 
...     items_url = "{}/content/users/{}/items/{}/status".format(agol_helper.secure_url,agol_helper.username, exportItemId)
...     data_url = "{}/content/items/{}/data".format(agol_helper.secure_url, exportItemId)
... 
...     status_parameters = {
...         'jobId' : jobId,
...         'jobType' : 'export',
...         'f' : 'json',
...         'token' : agol_helper.token
...     }
... 
...     while status == "processing":
...         print ("...." + status)
...         # checking export job status
...         time.sleep(5)
...         data = agol_helper.url_request(items_url, status_parameters)
... 
...         status = data['status']
... 
...     if status == "completed":
...         print ("...." + status)
...         # once the export has completed, download the file
...         downloadFile(data_url, download_file, agol_helper.token)
...         # deleting export results in the portal
...         agol_helper.delete(item_id=export_data['exportItemId'])
...         # uncompress the contents of the archive
...         extractZIP(download_file, download_folder)
... 
... 
...     else:
...         raise Exception("!!! Export job failed. Status \"" + status + "\"")
... 
...     print ("Completed. Files available at: " + download_folder )
...
```

[example of python code being ran in command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iw5j.jpg)

Comment: Your python script is not visible at that link.  Paste in the section that outputs the CSV and someone can show you how to have it write sql.

Comment: I posted the code in the second image.

Comment: Paste the code in text in your question and wrap with code tags

Comment: There you go! Thanks for the help

Comment: Okay, I thought I would see where the CSV is being generated.  But it's wrapped up in library methods.  Paste in a sample (two or three lines) from your CSV.  It is very easy to translate from CSV to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Python comes with an sqlite library:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html
Read carefully.

Comment: I still don't really understand what I need to do.